# Show set of affine transformations is a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am tasked to show that the set of affine transformations of [image],

[image]

Where S is an invertible linear transformation and b is a vector, forms a group under the composition of maps.

It was easy to show that [image]

Now I need to show that there is an identity element, and that all elements are invertible such that [image]

Im a little unsure what to do at this point....Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Comment: You should also prove that the composition of two affine transformation is also an affine transformation.

Comment: By linearity composition of affine transformations gives:
$$(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))=f(S_g (x)+b_g)=S_f(S_g (x)+b_g)+b_f=(S_f S_g)(x) + (S_f(b_g)+b_f) $$
Where $S_f S_g$ is again a linear transformation (matrix multiplication) and $(S_f(b_g)+b_f)$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the identity map, note that you are looking for a map such that both

$$e(f(x)) = f(x) = Sx+b$$

$$f(e(x)) = f(x) = Sx+b$$

This is obviously true for the map where $e(x)=Ix+0=x$.

To show that all elements are invertible means you are looking for a map where both

$$g(f(x)) = g(Sx+b) = S_2 (Sx+b)+b_2 = x$$

$$f(g(x)) = f(S_2x+b_2) = S(S_2x+b_2)+b = x$$

Doing some arithmetic, I think you'll be able to figure out what $S_2$ and $b_2$ end up being. Then because we defined $g(x)=S_2(x)+b_2$, it is trivially already in the group.

Comment: Ahh Thanks NoseKnowsAll! I will do just that..

Comment: g=S^(-1)(x)-S^(-1)b ?

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent Correct.